# SHAP plots for time series

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, shap

- Tensorflow: 2.11
- Shap: 0.42.1

I finally got Shap running with the above versions.The data are time series with 60 timestamps and four features. The ML model is a sequential model with Keras and LSTM:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()

import shap
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, trainx)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(trainx)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[0][:, 58, :], trainx[:0][:, 0, :], feature_names=features, plot_type="bar")
```

[image: bar plot]

My question: I can only display the bar plot for each timestamp, but not over the whole time series. Is this also possible for the whole time series?

Can I apply a Beeswarm Plot following the same pattern? Unfortunately, I only get an empty plot?

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[0][:, 58, :], trainx[:0][:, 0, :], feature_names=features, plot_type="beeswarm")
```

[image: emptyplot]